# Where do you put an object pool manager in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'd like to maintain an object/connection pool in an ASP.NET MVC application. The purpose of the pool is to improve performance by reusing connections to a third-party web service. The third-party web service requires a login call which returns a session ID - the pool saves these session IDs.

My question is, where do I instantiate this object pool so that it can be used across all requests? It will only be used by 1 controller but if I instantiate it in the controller I believe a new object pool will be instantiated for every user request even if it is a singleton?
Is it reasonable to store it in the Application state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are referring to as an *object pool* has a name: it's often called cache.

You could use the [`ObjectCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.objectcache.aspx) class and more specifically the [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) class which is one implementation of it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you implement your object/connection pool but if you follow the [Object Pooling Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/object-pool-pattern.html), you can simply apply Singleton pattern and do some initialization code(early loading) in Application_Start in global.asax.